# Trouble installing Visual C++ Redistributable 2008 in Windows 11 - Error 1935

Tags: visual-c++, windows-11

So I recently installed MSI Afterburner on my Windows 11 Machine, but after installing it won't open up. The probable issue was that I didn't have Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable installed. I have all other versions from 2010-2022.

But while installing the 2008 and 2005 redistributables I end up getting a 1935 error and the installer just rolls back.

[Error 1935 dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WmvS.png)

I searched it up and tried everything like running an sfc scan, disabling and enabling the .NET frameworks. I also checked my Registry Editor and it was all correct.

I checked the event logs and found this :

```
Activation context generation failed for "D:\MSI Afterburner\MSIAfterburner.exe". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.MFC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.
```

Then I figured out maybe there was problem with the WinSXS folder's permissions.
Turns out only the TrustedInsaller had full access to the folder and the subfolders.
So, I also tried changing the WinSXS folder's permissions manually, but in vain.

How do I fix this error? How do I change the WinSXS folder's permissions successfully?

Or is there any other fix to get MSI Afterburner up and running? Please help.

Comment: Are you running as an administrator?

Comment: You may find that https://superuser.com/ is the stack exchange site for this sort of question. I have had more success getting non-software dev computer issues resolved there.

Comment: wrong stack exchange. should be in superuser, i think

Comment: Did you get a solution? 
I am running with the similar problem and have already tried everything without any luck.

Answer (score -1):

This is rather peculiar. I know our systems can differ.

I have installed VS 2022 on a pristine Windows 11 system **without** MSI Afterburner.
Installed VS 2008 redistributable, no problem.

Again: pristine Windows **with** MSI Afterburner installed.
Installed VS 2008 redistributable, no errors.

Windows 11 Enterprise, Build 22000.co_release.210604-1628
Redistributable 9.0.21022.8 (2016)
MSI Afterburner 4.6.4 Beta, Riva Server 7.3.2 Beta.
After that installed redistributable 2005, no problem.

Did it happen while installing 2005 redistributable? Did you install any other software? It must be something specific to your system.